# Hangs at "compressToJpeg"

Tags: android

**See all 3 edits below**

**Update: Changed 'read()' to 'readFully()' and got some things working. 'decodeByteArray()' no longer returns null. The jpeg written to the card is actually a full image. The image is still not being drawn to my view. I will keep working and post another question if need be.**

I am writing a video streaming client program that takes in images from a DataInputStream.

Because the server calls compressToJpeg() on these images, I figured I could simply take the byte array from my DataInputStream, decode it, and draw the Bitmap from decodeByteArray() to my SurfaceView. Unfortunately, that method only leaves me with decodeByteArray() returning null.

So I added an intermediate step. I created a compressFrame() method which simply takes the byte array from the stream, creates a new YuvImage instance, and uses that to call compressToJpeg(). When run, however, this method *hangs on compressToJpeg* and *closes my client activity*. There is no FC popup, and I get no errors in my log.

I have provided the run() of the thread calling the problem method, the method itself, and the log printed before the app closes.

**EDIT:** I've also added the ReceiverUtils.getFrame() just in case.

```
@Override
public void run() {

    String fromServer = null;
    int jpgSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    byte[] jpgData;
    Bitmap image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream jpgBaos = null;

    while(isItOK && (receiver.textIn != null)){
        if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
            continue;
        }

        ReceiverUtils.init(holder);

        //Receive 'ready' flag from camcorder
        fromServer = ReceiverUtils.receiveText(receiver);

        while((fromServer != null)){

            Log.e("From server: ", fromServer); //logging here because of null pointers when done in Utils

            if(fromServer.startsWith("ANDROID_JPG_READY")){

                //Obtain size for byte array
                jpgSize = Integer.parseInt(fromServer.substring(18));
                Log.e("JPG SIZE", String.valueOf(jpgSize));

                //Create byte array of size jpgSize
                buffer = new byte[jpgSize];
                Log.e("BUFFER SIZE", String.valueOf(buffer.length));

                //Send flag and receive image data from camcorder
                ReceiverUtils.sendText(receiver, "ANDROID_JPG_SEND");
                jpgData = ReceiverUtils.receiveData(receiver, buffer);

                //Compress jpgData and write result to jpgBaos
                jpgBaos = ReceiverUtils.compressFrame(imgRect, jpgData);

                //Decode jpgData into Bitmap
                image = ReceiverUtils.getFrame(jpgBaos.toByteArray(), jpgSize);
                //image = ReceiverUtils.getFrame(jpgData, jpgSize);

                //Set buffer and jpgData to null since we aren't using them
                buffer = null;
                jpgData = null;

                //Draw Bitmap to canvas
                ReceiverUtils.draw(image, holder, imgRect);
                //break; (testing one run-through)
            }

            //Receive 'ready' flag from camcorder
            fromServer = ReceiverUtils.receiveText(receiver);
            if(isItOK == false){
                break;
            }
        }
        //break; (testing one run-through)
    }
    }
```

This is the ReceiverUtils.compressFrame() called in the previous snippet.

```
/*----------------------------------------
 * compressFrame(Rect imgRect, byte[] input): Creates new instance of YuvImage used to compress ARGB 
 * byte array data to jpeg. Returns ByteArrayOutputStream with data.    
 */

    public static ByteArrayOutputStream compressFrame(Rect imgRect, byte[] input){
        boolean success = false;

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(input, ImageFormat.NV21, 
                  imgRect.width(), imgRect.height(), null);
        Log.e("HEY", "HEY");
        success = yuvImage.compressToJpeg(imgRect, 80, baos);
        Log.e("Compression Success:", String.valueOf(success));

        return baos;
    }
```

Finally, this is the output I'm getting from my LogCat. (Beware some obviously hastily written debug logs.)

```
07-03 15:01:19.754: E/From server:(1634): ANDROID_JPG_READY_26907
07-03 15:01:19.754: E/JPG SIZE(1634): 26907
07-03 15:01:19.764: E/BUFFER SIZE(1634): 26907
07-03 15:01:19.764: E/To server:(1634): ANDROID_JPG_SEND
07-03 15:01:19.834: E/jpgIn(1634): Data received successfully.
07-03 15:01:19.834: E/HEY(1634): HEY
07-03 15:01:19.844: D/skia(1634): onFlyCompress
```

**EDIT: ReceiverUtils.getFrame()**

```
/*---------------------------------------
 * getFrame(byte[] jpgData, int jpgSize): Decodes a byte array into a Bitmap and 
 * returns the Bitmap.
 */
    public static Bitmap getFrame(byte[] jpgData, int jpgSize){
        Bitmap res = null;

        res = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpgData, 0, jpgSize);
        Log.e("Decode success", String.valueOf(!(res == null)));            

        return res;
    }
```

**EDIT 2: Code before adding compression**

```
//Compress jpgData and write result to jpgBaos
//jpgBaos = ReceiverUtils.compressFrame(imgRect, jpgData);

//Decode jpgData into Bitmap
//image = ReceiverUtils.getFrame(jpgBaos.toByteArray(), jpgSize);
image = ReceiverUtils.getFrame(jpgData, jpgSize);
```

**EDIT 3: Image after saved to SD Card**

The image that Android holds in 'jpgData' in the first code snippet is not the entire image. I can't post it due to being a new user. I added a 'writeToSD' method to test. I assume that the reason it cannot be decoded is because the majority of the image is just blank space, and only a portion of the image is there.

Comment: Where is `imgRect` initialized or set to the correct size?

Comment: The class this is in implements Runnable, and imgRect is in the constructor of that class.

Comment: Hmm. To be honest, I'm not sure why your original `decodeByteArray()` would come back null, having not seen that code. That's the normal way to handle jpeg data, this coversion to yuv and back seems like it's unneeded.

Comment: I didn't think it was. This was just one of my attempted solutions. Is there anything I could provide that would help out?

Comment: If you still have the code you were using when it was throwing null, that would be useful. Assuming the server is sending you a valid jpeg byte array(not throwing some kind of odd header or anything on it), it should be able to go straight into decodeByteArray().

Comment: I added the code. It's really just some comment changes. I left the lines there to be able to go back and forth.

Comment: To verify that the server is sending a valid byte array, what happens if you save the array directly to disk and open it with a viewer?

Comment: I will test this when I'm back in the lab tomorrow.

Comment: I will say that we have a C++ client running on a windows machine that reads the data coming from the server perfectly fine and displays the video stream.

Comment: See my new edit @Geobits